# JsonConvert with number as item name

Tags: json

I have extracted the below json from ETH. So this is a valid json.

```
"networks": {
  "18": {
    "address": "0x478a2763d239b60206006437f5154dad59fef909"
  }
}
```

Trying to parse using:

```
dynamic Obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(".... json string .....");

Obj.Networks.18.address;  // Error

Obj.SelectToken("networks.18.address"); // Null
```

I can't even compile because a label name cannot start with number.

May I know what is the correct way to access the address?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model that represents the data

```
public class RootObject {
    public Dictionary<string, network> networks { get; set; }
}

public class network {
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

And use that to access the desired information

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(".... json string .....");
var address = data.networks["18"].address;
```

because of the syntax conflict, string `Dictionary` was used as a workaround to be able to access the key value pair.